# Angular UI-router resolve data gets undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following the instructions on the [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) which relates to working with resolves. If I follow the instructions on the wiki I get the value shared in to the controller without an issue, if I include the controller by reference the value is undefined. What am i missing?

```
.state('intro', {
            url: '/',
            resolve:{
                resA:  function(){
                    return {'value': 'A'};
                }
            },
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: function($scope, resA){
                  $scope.resA = resA.value;
                }
            },
            'navigation': {
                templateUrl: 'views/navigation.html'

            }

        } })
```

---

```
    .controller('introController', ['$scope', function($scope,resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value; //undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you did not include `resA` in your array notation, it should be like this:

```
.controller('introController', ['$scope', 'resA', function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wFJ5ZaVGNb4Y2DoBgo5?p=preview)

We have to declare this controller, e.g. as a part of state def:

```
'navigation': {
     template: '<div>navi - resA: {{resA}}</div>',
     controller: 'introController',
},
```

then we have to properly pass arguments (the 'resA' must be passed as well)

```
 .controller('introController', ['$scope', 'resA'
 , function($scope,resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value; //undefined
 }])
;
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wFJ5ZaVGNb4Y2DoBgo5?p=preview)